# AlmondJS - Require external url

Tags: javascript, requirejs, almond

In one of my AMD modules I have

```
 require(["//google-analytics.com/analytics.js"]);
```

It works with requireJS, but, when using almond, I get "Uncaught Error: undefined missing //google-analytics.com/analytics.js" error.

Does this mean almond does not support requiring external scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean almond does not support requiring external scripts?

Yes, that's exactly what it means. From the ["Restrictions" section](https://github.com/jrburke/almond#restrictions) , very first item:

> optimize all the modules into one file -- **no dynamic code loading.**

(Emphasis added.)

Answer (score 0):

Just read one of the almondjs authors comment on github - looks like external scripts are not and won't be supported in near future.

[Link to github issue](https://github.com/jrburke/almond/issues/11)